# If the lake contains a total of 1000 fish with 100 of them marked, what is the probability that when you catch 10 fish at least one of them is marked

Tags: probability, statistics, poisson-distribution

Since 100 fish are marked out of 1000, the chance would be 0.1, so it would be X = Bin(1000, .01)? If want to calculate P(X>=1), where X is the number of fish, would I used to poisson distribution?

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Anything to do with fish requires the Poisson distribution. :-)

Comment: You can do this by using the poisson approximation to the binomial distribution. See here http://courses.wcupa.edu/rbove/Berenson/10th%20ed%20CD-ROM%20topics/section5_6.pdf

Answer (score 3):

Go step-by-step. Calculate what's the probability of not catching a marked fish in $10$ tries. At first there are $1000$ fishes and $100$ are marked, so there's $\frac {900}{1000}$ you won't caught a marked fish. Now let's fish again. $999$ fishes and $899$ unmarked. Do this $10$ times and you'll get:

$$\frac{900}{1000} \times \frac{899}{999} \times \cdots \times \frac{891}{991} \approx 34.69 \%$$

So now just subtract that from $100 \%$ and there's $65.31 \%$ you'll get at least one marked fish in 10 tries.

Comment: By comparison, if you just do $(900/1000)^10$, you get $34.87\%$ and $65.13\%$ respectively.

Comment: @Michael It's seems that the results are close (of course you way is the wrong one), but the difference would grow bigger and bigger as the number of tries get bigger. Also $\frac 900{1000}$ is "fairly" close to one and the numbers are "realitively" big so that's why the answers don't differ too much.

Comment: I do not think I am catching the fish one by one. Rather I catch 10 fish at a time. I somehow think its a combination problem. What do you think?

Comment: Note that $34.69\%$ is a bit less than $1/e$. If $1/20$ of a large population of fish were marked and you caught $20$, the probability of having no marked fish would again be approximately $1/e$.

Comment: That's because: $\left(\frac{900}{1000}\right)^{10} = \left(1 - \frac 1{10}\right)^{10}$ and we know that as $n$ becomes larger the expression has a value of $\frac 1e$

Comment: @user221422 Well since the events are independent (the 5th catch won't afect the 6th an so on), you can split all the cathces. Look like this: You catch 10 fishes simultaniously and then extract one from the bunch and if that's not marked, you now that the chances of getting a marked fish are growing and so on.

Comment: @user221422 If you want a much more combinatorial proof, check this. How many ways are there to chose 0 fishes from 100? $\binom{100}{0} = 1$. How many ways are there to chose 10 fihes out of 900? $\binom{900}{10}$. And how many ways are there to chose 10 fishes out of 1000? $\binom{1000}{10}$. So the probability is:

$$\frac{\binom{100}{0} \times \binom{900}{10}}{\binom{1000}{10}}$$

which after much factorization and canceling comes down to the simplier form I've used.

Answer (score 1):

This is hypergeometric. An urn (the lake) has 100 red balls (marked fish) in 1000.
We sample 10. The random variable X is the hypergeometric. We seek
$P(X \ge 1) = 1 - P(X = 0),$  where

P(X = 0) = C(100, 0)C(900,10)/C(1000,10) = 0.3469.

Here I have used C to denote a binomial coefficient.

In R, either 'choose(900,10)/choose(1000,10)' or 'dhyper(0, 100, 900, 10)'
will return this result. In general for larger numbers, calculations of such probabilities can overflow a
computer (or calculator) along the way. The second R statement is optimized to avoid
such difficulties.

The **Capture-Recapture method** of estimating the number of fish in a lake
is a two-step process. First, capture c fish at random and mark them
(here c = 100). Second, after fish have time to randomly mix themselves,
capture r fish at random (here r = 10), and note the number x of marked
fish among the r.

Estimating the number T of fish in the lake involves equating the proportion of marked fish in the lake c/T = 100/T to the proportion of marked fish in the sample x/r = x/10, then solving for T. In general T is estimated by
t = cr/x (here t = 100(10)/x). So if you caught x = 2 marked fish,
you would estimate T as 1000/2 = 500. Here the values of c and r are too
small for a good estimate.

This method does not work if x = 0. *So there is a practical basis for asking
the original question.* Modified estimators such as t = (c+1)(r+1)/(x+1) are
often mentioned as avoiding division by 0 and also giving somewhat better
estimates of T.

The hypergeometric distribution can be used to find confidence intervals for
the estimate of T. There is rich literature capture-recapture methods, which
have been used in many ecological settings, but also to estimate certain
human populations. Variations seek to adjust for 'fish' that immigrate, emigrate,
die, or give birth between the capture and recapture phases. (If you search
the web, try to stick to probability texts and articles in reputable journals, there is a lot of
total nonsense on this topic.)